# October CMS build 467 issue with opening cms files

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins, octobercms-backend

I have just loaded October CMS build 467, now I am having trouble accessing my CSS files they are there part of the theme but when I click on the CSS file name it says TEMPLATE NOT FOUND. I have attached a screenshot.

Has anyone had this issue and know how to get around it.

[image]

Comment: hmm i tested and seems working fine for me, may be just try to change theme to default and set your theme back. it should solve your issue

Comment: Tried that, it is still doing it in fact was doing doing it on the template too, I have even updated WAMP, reinstalled the database. this one is driving me mad. could windows firewall be blocking scripts.